# Live Location Tracking on IOS device while application is terminated or in background

Tags: ios, core-location

I’m working on an application that needs to track User’s real time location after every x time interval for their safety.

I have set `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` in my Location Manager settings that gives a Location Update trigger even when my application is terminated. On location update change trigger I’m sharing device location with my Server through REST API.

But I’m unable to find any solution which can provide time-based location changes when my application is terminated or in background.

Comment: You can't trigger background execution based on a specific time or elapsed time.

Comment: but whatsapp is doing live tracking, while application is terminated. any idea how they are implementing it.

Comment: I don't use that app, so I don't know exactly what you are referring to, but they could use significant location tracking

Comment: I think at @Paulw11 is right - obviously if the user hasn't moved you can record server side timer that the user hasn't moved, you don't need the app for that. I am not sure what WhatsApp is exactly doing, but according to your description everything can be done server side.